# Why my simple jQuery code doesn't work with .css() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following simple code but it seem that not work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function($)
    {
        $(window).resize(
            function()
            {
                setGrid($);
            }
        );

        setGrid($);
    }
);

function setGrid($)
{
    var contactContainer    =   $('#contactInfo');

    if(contactContainer.width() < 650)
    {
        console.log('Too short');
        $('.col_1_2').css(
            {
                width     :   '100% !important',
                margin    :   '0 !important'
            }
        );
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Too long');

        $('.col_1_2').css(
            {
                width       :   '49% !important',
                marginRight :   '1% !important'
            }
        );

        $('.last').css(
            {
                width       :   '49% !important',
                marginRight :   '0 !important',
                marginLeft  :   '1% !important'
            }
        );
    }
}
```

So, when I resize the window I am getting both the messages in my Chrome console, according to the #containerInfo, but the .col_1_2 are not updated.

Is there anything wrong in my code and I cannot find it out ?

**Note :** I have my console open and I do not get any error message in my console. Also in the "Elements" tab of my console I am inspecting the element that must get modified, and I do not see any change. Normaly a "style" attribute should be added on the matched element.

Kind regards

Comment: y r u calling the   setGrid($) function twice???

Comment: first time run imediatly when the document is ready, the second one running on window resize.

Comment: What is it for? What are you trying to do with `$` like that? Can't you do this in pure CSS with mediaqueries? I don't know, something doesn't look right, setting `!important` in jQuery like that...

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      setGrid($);
        $(window).resize(
            function()
            {
                setGrid($);
            }
        );

});

isnt dis gonna work??

Comment: What if you put return; after the first call to setGrid($); ?

Comment: @elclanrs this cannot be set via media queries in CSS because I am writing a meta box for WordPress custom post. So the #contactInfo element doesn't have width related to document width. Also I have try !important again in the past and works fine with jQuery .css() method

Comment: Try taking off the !important... you don't need them, as styles applied with .css get added to the element directly (overriding any other styles that may apply).

Comment: @Shashank, why isn't gonna work ? I did console log on variable contactContainer and works properly !

Comment: Then WordPress probably has a hook that you can use. It just looks like the wrong approach, no matter the environment.

Comment: @PhillipWills please add answer. This worked for me :) I will upvote you. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try taking off the !important... you don't need them, as styles applied with .css get added to the element directly (overriding any other styles that may apply).

Comment: Weird that it works but i cant argue with results ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, You are missing `'(quote)` in attribute. Add `quote` in all css then it will work.

```
$('.col_1_2').css(
        {
            'width'       :   '49% !important',
            'margin-right' :   '1% !important'
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already have try this but still no work.

Comment: @MerianosNikos Can you set fiddle

Comment: @Merianos enter the css in stylesheet and
try using add class remove class on resize event..

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Object literal property names do not need quotes in cases where the names follow standard JS identifier limitations. (Object literal property names do need quotes when they contain spaces or punctuation or whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery will not allow to set !important as you have tried. However, I think the following will work for you.

```
jQuery.style(name, value, priority);
```

You can use it to get values with .style('name') just like .css('name'), get the CSSStyleDeclaration with .style(), and also set values - with the ability to specify the priority as 'important'. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration.

Try something like:

```
var div = $('someDiv');
console.log(div.style('color'));
div.style('color', 'red');
console.log(div.style('color'));
div.style('color', 'blue', 'important');
console.log(div.style('color'));
console.log(div.style().getPropertyPriority('color'));
```

However, using media query is the correct way to proceed.